# How to uninstall python package in Apache Airflow

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, package, airflow

We are using Apache Airflow through AWS.
We have a requirements.txt with all of our python packages and we ran into a problem.

---

At one point, we inserted the following packges , updated the enviroment, and it worked for a few weeks:

kubernetes

apache-airflow[postgres,aws]==1.10.12

apache-airflow-backport-providers-postgres==2020.6.24

**apache-airflow-backport-providers-amazon==2021.3.3**

pandas==1.2.3

python-dateutil==2.8.1

smart-open==5.1.0

fsspec==2021.6.1

s3fs==2021.6.1

xlrd==2.0.1

openpyxl==3.0.7

**boto3**

**aiobotocore**

**botocore**

---

The problem:

We must use apache-airflow-backport-providers-amazon: it depends on botocore being: 1.19.0 < botocore >= 1.18.0

boto3 depends on: 1.19.0 < botocore >= 1.18.18

aiobotocore depends on: botocore that doesn't match these version that I listed above.

And that is exactly our problem. Now the enviorment doesn't work because it can't install requirements.txt, as this dependecny fails it.

I believe that if I manage to remove aiobotocore, it would work.

Its good to note that I removed aiobotocore from requirements.txt and it still shows that aiobotocre depends on botocore and it fails the requirements.txt (when updating the enviorment).

I am sort of new to Python so excuse me if something was written poorly. If anyone has any suggestions, it would be a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't manage to find a way to uninstall/remove a package.

Ended up rolling back the version of "requirements.txt" when editing the airflow enviroment and it seems as it uninstalled the packages.